# C Hash table implementation

Tags: performance, c, hash-map

I have written a pretty simple hash table in C. It uses a prime modulus, linear probing, open addressing, and robin hood hashing.
The program can also be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/Levalicious/ftable/blob/fb968268ed0cc9225f208f7e6d17584f1efa6d90/ftable.h).

For clarification, `uin` is a typedef that uses `uint32_t` or `uint64_t` depending on whether the system is x86 or x86_64.

I'd now like to optimize the performance as much as possible, but I'm unsure of how to do so.
I've considered using fastrange or fibonacci hashing instead of a prime modulus and consistent hashing to speed up the resizes. However, I'd like to streamline it beforehand. My apologies for the gotos, I know they are evil (but I kinda like them I'm sorry).
I'd appreciate any feedback.

```
#ifndef FTABLE_FTABLE_H
#define FTABLE_FTABLE_H

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LOAD 0.5

/* Set uin as uint32_t or uint64_t depending on system */
#ifdef __x86
typedef uint32_t uin;

/* Table of prime number sizes, each approx double the prev, that fits
 * into a uint32_t */
const uin tableSizes[] = {
        5, 11, 23, 47, 97, 197, 397, 797, 1597,
        3203, 6421, 12853, 25717, 51437, 102877,
        205759, 411527, 823117, 1646237, 3292489,
        6584983, 13169977, 26339969, 52679969,
        105359939, 210719881, 421439783, 842879579,
        1685759167, 3371518343 };

#elif __x86_64
typedef uint64_t uin;

/* Table of prime number sizes, each approx double the prev, that fits
 * into a uint64_t */
const uin tableSizes[] = {
        5, 11, 23, 47, 97, 197, 397, 797, 1597,
        3203, 6421, 12853, 25717, 51437, 102877,
        205759, 411527, 823117, 1646237, 3292489,
        6584983, 13169977, 26339969, 52679969,
        105359939, 210719881, 421439783, 842879579,
        1685759167, 3371518343, 6743036717, 13486073473,
        26972146961, 53944293929, 107888587883,
        215777175787, 431554351609, 863108703229,
        1726217406467, 3452434812973, 6904869625999,
        13809739252051, 27619478504183, 55238957008387,
        110477914016779, 220955828033581, 441911656067171,
        883823312134381, 1767646624268779, 3535293248537579,
        7070586497075177, 14141172994150357,
        28282345988300791, 56564691976601587,
        113129383953203213, 226258767906406483,
        452517535812813007, 905035071625626043,
        1810070143251252131, 3620140286502504283,
        7240280573005008577, 14480561146010017169,
        18446744073709551557};

#endif

/* Table of bitmasks to use */
const uin mask[] = {
        0x7,                0xF,
        0x1F,               0x3F,               0x7F,               0xFF,
        0x1FF,              0x3FF,              0x7FF,              0xFFF,
        0x1FFF,             0x3FFF,             0x7FFF,             0xFFFF,
        0x1FFFF,            0x3FFFF,            0x7FFFF,            0xFFFFF,
        0x1FFFFF,           0x3FFFFF,           0x7FFFFF,           0xFFFFFF,
        0x1FFFFFF,          0x3FFFFFF,          0x7FFFFFF,          0xFFFFFFF,
        0x1FFFFFFF,         0x3FFFFFFF,         0x7FFFFFFF,         0xFFFFFFFF,
        0x1FFFFFFFF,        0x3FFFFFFFF,        0x7FFFFFFFF,        0xFFFFFFFFF,
        0x1FFFFFFFFF,       0x3FFFFFFFFF,       0x7FFFFFFFFF,       0xFFFFFFFFFF,
        0x1FFFFFFFFFF,      0x3FFFFFFFFFF,      0x7FFFFFFFFFF,      0xFFFFFFFFFFF,
        0x1FFFFFFFFFFF,     0x3FFFFFFFFFFF,     0x7FFFFFFFFFFF,     0xFFFFFFFFFFFF,
        0x1FFFFFFFFFFFF,    0x3FFFFFFFFFFFF,    0x7FFFFFFFFFFFF,    0xFFFFFFFFFFFFF,
        0x1FFFFFFFFFFFFF,   0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFF,   0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFF,   0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,
        0x1FFFFFFFFFFFFFF,  0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFF,  0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFF,  0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,
        0x1FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,

};

/* Linear probing max distance */
#define MAX_PROBES 10

/* Bucket States: Empty, Occupied, Tombstone */
#define EMPTY 0
#define OCCPD 1
#define TMBSTN 2

typedef struct sftbl_bckt ftbucket;

/* Hash table bucket: Key, value, distance from 'ideal' position,
 * and data field indicating the bucket state */
struct sftbl_bckt {
    uin key;
    uin val;
    uint8_t dist;
    uint8_t data;
};

typedef struct sftbl ftable;

struct sftbl {
    ftbucket* buckets;
    uin size;
    uin count;
    uint8_t lvl;
};

ftable* alloc_ftable() {
    ftable* out = malloc(sizeof(ftable));
    memset(out, 0, sizeof(ftable));
    return out;
}

ftable* insert(ftable* ft, uin key, uin val);

void free_table(ftable* ft);

ftable* resize(ftable* ft) {
    ftable* nt = malloc(sizeof(ftable));

    /* Increase the index in the prime table used for the size */
    nt->lvl = ft->lvl + 1;
    nt->size = tableSizes[nt->lvl];;
    nt->count = 0;

    nt->buckets = malloc(sizeof(ftbucket) * nt->size);

    memset(nt->buckets, 0, sizeof(ftbucket) * nt->size);

    /* Iterate through every valid entry and insert into new table */
    for (uin i = 0; i < ft->size; i++) {
        if (ft->buckets[i].data == OCCPD) {
            nt = insert(nt, ft->buckets[i].key, ft->buckets[i].val);
        }
    }

    /* Free old table and return new one */

    free_table(ft);

    return nt;
}

ftable* insert(ftable* ft, uin key, uin val) {
    if (((float) ft->count + 1) / ((float) ft->size) > MAX_LOAD) {
        ft = resize(ft);
    }

    binsert:;
    /* Prime modulus */
    uin index = key % ft->size;
    uint8_t dist = 0;
    while (1) {
        /* If more than MAX_PROBES away from ideal location
         * resize table and attempt to insert again (goto binsert) */
        if (dist > MAX_PROBES) {
            ft = resize(ft);
            goto binsert;
        }
        // uin nind = (index + dist) % ft->size;
        uin nind = (index + dist) & mask[ft->lvl];
        /**
         * Above line can be replaced with
         * uin nind = (index + dist) & mask[ft->lvl];
         * for worse memory usage but faster perf
         **/
        if (ft->buckets[nind].data == OCCPD) {
            if (ft->buckets[nind].dist < dist) {
                /* Robin hood hashing: If a 'richer' node is found, 
                 * steal from it: swap */
                uin tkey = ft->buckets[nind].key;
                uin tval = ft->buckets[nind].val;
                uint8_t tdist = ft->buckets[nind].dist;
                ft->buckets[nind].key = key;
                ft->buckets[nind].val = val;
                ft->buckets[nind].dist = dist;
                key = tkey;
                val = tval;
                dist = tdist;
            }
        }
        if (ft->buckets[nind].data == EMPTY || ft->buckets[index + dist].data == TMBSTN) {
            /* Occupy any empty or tombstone buckets */
            ft->buckets[nind].data = OCCPD;
            ft->buckets[nind].key = key;
            ft->buckets[nind].val = val;
            ft->buckets[nind].dist = dist;
            ft->count++;
            return ft;
        }

        dist++;
    }
}

void delete(ftable* ft, uin key) {
    uin index = key % ft->size;
    uint8_t dist = 0;
    while (1) {
        if (dist > MAX_PROBES) {
            /* Object not present in table. Return. */
            return;
        }
        // uin nind = (index + dist) % ft->size;
        uin nind = (index + dist) & mask[ft->lvl];
        /**
         * Above line can be replaced with
         * uin nind = (index + dist) & mask[ft->lvl];
         * for worse memory usage but faster perf
         **/
        if (ft->buckets[nind].data == OCCPD) {
            if (ft->buckets[nind].key == key) {
                /* Set bucket data to tombstone and
                 * clear key and value */
                ft->buckets[nind].data = TMBSTN;
                ft->buckets[nind].key = 0;
                ft->buckets[nind].val = 0;
                ft->count--;
                return;
            }
        }

        dist++;
    }
}

uin get(ftable* ft, uin key) {
    uin index = key % ft->size;
    uint8_t dist = 0;
    while (1) {
        if (dist > MAX_PROBES) {
            /* Object not present in table. Return. */
            perror("Went over max probes!");
            return -1;
        }
        // uin nind = (index + dist) % ft->size;
        uin nind = (index + dist) & mask[ft->lvl];
        /**
         * Above line can be replaced with
         * uin nind = (index + dist) & mask[ft->lvl];
         * for worse memory usage but faster perf
         **/
        if (ft->buckets[nind].data == OCCPD) {
            if (ft->buckets[nind].key == key) {
                return ft->buckets[nind].val;
            }
        } else if (ft->buckets[nind].data == EMPTY) {
            /* If empty, return early. Further elements
             * would have been bridged by a tombstone or a 
             * occupied bucket. */
            return -1;
        }

        dist++;
    }
}

void free_table(ftable* ft) {
    free(ft->buckets);
    free(ft);
}

#endif
```

Comment: I suggest you to better write long names instead of short and cryptic ones (I used to do that so under my first year programing). In the future (perhaps) it would be difficult for you to understand those small names and using `typedef` does not help.

Comment: @MiguelAvila I'll keep that in mind for the future! For this piece of code, if the name isn't self explanatory, its probably something I just stuck a letter or 2 onto the front of. I'll add improving the variable names to my to do list.

Comment: In addition: I've since changed the implementation to use a bitmask inside of the while loops instead of the modulus. It's improved performance some and seems to not be affecting the average load of the table or memory usage.

Comment: Do you have any unit tests that exercise the code, that would be good as well.

Comment: In contrast to some interpreters in the dawn of HLLs in *home computing*, programs don't get any faster by omitting [comments](https://www.doxygen.nl/index.html), let alone algorithms.

Comment: @greybeard I've edited to include some comments. I hope they help clarify the code somewhat. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Note to anyone on VTC, I have removed my VTC, there is now enough code to review.

Comment: For context, I was worried with the performance on this table and I couldn't figure out why it was as slow as it seemed to be. Turns out it was because I was printing microseconds instead of milliseconds for the benchmark and making myself think it was 1000x slower. I figured that out about 10 minutes ago. However I'm sure there's still a lot I could've written more efficiently, so I'm still interested in improving it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some things that may help you improve your code.

### Separate interface from implementation

It makes the code somewhat longer for a code review, but it's often very useful to separate the interface from the implementation.  In C, this is usually done by putting the interface into separate `.h` files and the corresponding implementation into `.c` files.  It helps users (or reviewers) of the code see and understand the interface and hides implementation details.  The other important reason is that you might have multiple source files including the `.h` file but only one instance of the corresponding `.c` file.  In other words, split your existing `.h` file into a `.h` file and a `.c` file.

### Make sure you have all required `#include`s

The code uses `perror` but doesn't `#include <stdio.h>`.  Also, carefully consider which `#include`s are part of the interface (and belong in the `.h` file) and which are part of the implementation per the above advice.

### Don't print from a library

Because you're creating something like a library that might be called by many different kinds of programs, the code should not print anything or assume that there even is anything on which to print.  For that reason, I would strongly advise removing the `perror` line.

### Provide complete code to reviewers

This is not so much a change to the code as a change in how you present it to other people.  Without the full context of the code and an example of how to use it, it takes more effort for other people to understand your code.  This affects not only code reviews, but also maintenance of the code in the future, by you or by others.  One good way to address that is by the use of comments.  Another good technique is to include test code showing how your code is intended to be used.  Here's code I wrote to try out your functions:

```
#include "ftable.h"
#include <assert.h>

int main() {
    ftable *hash = alloc_ftable();
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        hash = insert(hash, i, i*i);
    }
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        assert(i*i == get(hash, i));
    }
    // delete odd keys
    for (unsigned i = 1; i < 100; i += 2) {
        delete(hash, i);
    }
    // verify that it's still correct
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        if (i & 1) {
            assert((uin)-1 == get(hash, i));
        } else {
            assert(i*i == get(hash, i));
        }
    }
    // resize hash table
    hash = resize(hash);
    // verify that it's still correct
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        if (i & 1) {
            assert((uin)-1 == get(hash, i));
        } else {
            assert(i*i == get(hash, i));
        }
    }
    free_table(hash);
}
```

### Measure the performance before and after any changes

As with the test function above, you should write many different test functions for your hash and measure their performance.  It's only by actually measuring before and after any change that you will be able to tell for certain whether you are improving or worsening the performance.

### Consider using better naming

Although some of the names are quite brief, I didn't have much difficulty in understanding them, so I think the current names are adequate.  However, although you as the programmer are interested in the hash table mechanism, from another programmer's point of view trying to *use* this code, it would probably be better to call it a `map` or `hashmap` or even `associative_array` because that's essentially what the code is for, even if the details happen to feature a hashing algorithm internally.  Also, it seems to me that `resize` should probably not be used other than internally.  For that reason, I'd suggest that it should be `static` and solely within `ftable.c`.  Also `data` should clearly be `state` or `bucket_state`.

### Combine `typedef` with `struct` declaration

It's purely a stylistic preference, but if you're going to use `typedef`s for your `struct`s, you should know that it's common practice to combine them for brevity and clarity:

```
typedef struct sftbl {
    ftbucket* buckets;
    unsigned size;
    unsigned count;
    uint8_t lvl;
} ftable;
```

### Use `const` where practical

In the `get` routine, the underlying structure is not modified and so that parameter should be declared `const` to signal that fact:

```
uin get(const ftable* ft, uin key);
```

### Check the return value of `malloc`

If the system is running out of memory, `malloc` will return `NULL`.  Code **must** check the return value to make sure it is not `NULL` before dereferencing the variable or the program will crash.

### Consider `unsigned` instead of a custom type

The code currently won't compile for an ARM processor since neither `__x86` nor `__x86_64` are defined for that processor type.  That's not really a necessary restriction, so I'd recommend instead simply using `unsigned` and making the `typedef` like this:

```
#include <limits.h>

#if UINT_MAX == 4294967295u
    // 32-bit version
#elif UINT_MAX == 18446744073709551615u
    // 64-bit version
#else 
    #error "unsigned type does not appear to be 32- or 64-bit value."
#endif
```

### Understand constant values

In C, when you write a value like `14480561146010017169` or `0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFF` it is interpreted by the preprocessor as a signed value.  If you want unsigned values, you must say so, so these constants should be written as `14480561146010017169u` or `0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFu` with the trailing `u` signifying unsigned.  Also, your `mask` values should be sized appropriately as per the previous advice.

### Goto is **still** considered dangerous

The `goto` in this code makes a difficult-to-understand control flow even more difficult to understand.  That is not a good idea.  So first let's look at the dubious `while(1)` loop.  Does it *really* never exit?  No, that's misleading.  If we study the code, we see it exits when it's able to place the data in a bucket.  So instead of `while(1)`, I would write this:

```
unsigned nind = index & mask[ft->lvl];
for (dist = 0;
     ft->buckets[nind].data != EMPTY && ft->buckets[index + dist].data != TMBSTN;
     ++dist) 
{  
    // the loop
}

/* Write the data in this bucket */
ft->buckets[nind].data = OCCPD;
ft->buckets[nind].key = key;
ft->buckets[nind].val = val;
ft->buckets[nind].dist = dist;
ft->count++;
return ft;
```

Now we can eliminate the `goto` by rewriting the clause within the loop:

```
if (dist > MAX_PROBES) {
    ft = resize(ft);
    index = key % ft->size;
    nind = index & mask[ft->lvl];
    dist = 0;
    continue;
}
```

A similar transformation can be applied elsewhere as with `get`:

```
unsigned get(const ftable* ft, unsigned key) {
    unsigned index = key % ft->size;
    unsigned retval = -1;
    for (uint8_t dist = 0; dist <= MAX_PROBES; ++dist) {
        unsigned nind = (index + dist) & mask[ft->lvl];
        if (ft->buckets[nind].data == OCCPD && ft->buckets[nind].key == key) {
            retval = ft->buckets[nind].val;
            break;
        } else if (ft->buckets[nind].data == EMPTY) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return retval;
}
```

### Use library calls efficiently

Instead of these two lines:

```
nt->buckets = malloc(sizeof(ftbucket) * nt->size);
memset(nt->buckets, 0, sizeof(ftbucket) * nt->size);
```

I'd write this:

```
nt->buckets = calloc(nt->size, sizeof(ftbucket));
```

### Avoid C++ keywords

There may come a time that you or someone else wants to incorporate this C code into a C++ project.  Unfortunately, the `delete` function sits atop the C++ reserved word `delete`.  Rename it to `remove` to avoid such clashes.

Comment: If I could up vote twice, I would. You got everything I wanted to write about.

Comment: @pacmaninbw: you did good work too, guiding the OP toward creating a reviewable question.  Kudos!

Comment: Thank you both for your help! I appreciate the advice and will get to work on fixing up my code!

Answer (score 2):

**Use valid constants**

`14480561146010017169, 18446744073709551557` are typically outside the `long long` range.  Append a `u`.

**Simplify allocation sizing**

Insptead of `p = some_alloc(sizeof(matching pointer type) * n)`, use `p = some_alloc(sizeof *p * n)`.  It is easier to code right, review and maintain.

```
// nt->buckets = malloc(sizeof(ftbucket) * nt->size);
nt->buckets = malloc(sizeof *(nt->buckets) * nt->size);
```

**Use `size_t` for indexing**

`uin` is not the best type for array index, it may be too narrow or wide for array indexing and sizing.  Use `size_t`.

I'd reccomend `unsigned long long` or `uintmax_t` for the *key* type though.

**Avoid FP math** for an integer problem.

```
//if (((float) ft->count + 1) / ((float) ft->size) > MAX_LOAD) {
//    ft = resize(ft);
//}

#define MAX_LOAD_N 1
#define MAX_LOAD_D 2
// if ((ft->count + 1) / ft->size > MAX_LOAD_N / MAX_LOAD_D) {
if ((ft->count+1) / MAX_LOAD_N > ft->size / MAX_LOAD_D) {
    ft = resize(ft);
}
```